# How can I show the validation messages in TextFormField from the API Response?

Tags: flutter

I need to display the TextField validation error messages based on API Response error message. Is there any way to identify text fields by any Unique ID or something?

I had a form with 5 TextFields.
I need to show the Individual error messages to the TextField validation messages that come from API Response.

Comment: can u share your 5 textfield code here ? so that it will be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyFormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyFormPage({super.key});

  @override
  MyFormPageState createState() {
    return MyFormPageState();
  }
}

class MyFormPageState extends State<MyFormPage> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  bool _hasError = false;
  String? _errorMessage;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> validate() async {
    String? errorMessage = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://your.api/validate'),
      body: {
        'your_field': _controller.text,
      },
    );

    if (mounted) {
      if (errorMessage != null) {
        setState(() {
          _hasError = true;
          _errorMessage = errorMessage;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('TextField Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Show Error Message Based On API Response',
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enter the Value',
                errorText: _hasError ? _errorMessage : null,
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: validate,
              child: const Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When you press the button, it'll make an API call, and if an error message is returned it'll be shown as the error message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the simplest code, as you already said you have five text fields, you might need to manage the state inside a class or something for a clean solution.

Comment: In here, you are writing all the api integration and the other UI codes in a specific file. But what if I am following an Architecture like DDD or MVC, and I need to separate all the source codes by structure wise?

Comment: as said in the earlier comment, it's the simplest example just demonstrating the usage. tweak this to the actual architecture you're using in the project.